# Command Line Tool in Bash to Build Directory Tree?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, directory

I have a bash script which takes a mix of template files and data which are layed out hierarchically in a directory named `INPUT`.

The script does the following:

1. Creates a hierarchical file output structure, `OUTPUT`
2. Populates said file tree with filtered/postprocessed data.
3. Runs some external programs for visualization, etc. on said data.

As I want this script to be as portable as possible and make it easy for colleagues to run it, I don't want to premake the `OUTPUT` folder structure externally, I want to generate it on the fly.

Unfortunately this creates a large text glob.

Currently I have something like:

```
$!/bin/bash

function MkdirAndAssign() { mkdir -p $1; echo $1; }

baseDir=$( pwd )
outDir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${baseDir}/OUTPUT )
outTop1Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outDir}/TOP1 )
outMid1_1Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outTop1Dir}/MID1_1 )
outMid1_2Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outTop1Dir}/MID1_2 )
outMid1_3Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outTop1Dir}/MID1_3 )
outBottom1_3_1Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outMid1_3Dir} )
outTop2Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outDir}/TOP2 )
outTop3Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outDir}/TOP3 )
outMid3_1Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outTop1Dir}/MID3_1 )
outMid3_2Dir=$( MkdirAndAssign ${outTop1Dir}/MID3_2 )
```

Of course those are just made up directory names... my real ones have actual meaning... but the key thing is I'm building this big set of nested directories.

My question:

Is there some sort of shell command that can make this shorter and sweeter??

(Note my function basically just wraps `mkdir -p` such that I can get a variable assignment in one command, for later reuse.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is any other tool hiding anywhere that would make it simpler. If you are creating on the fly, the only other option I see is some scheme where you hold the generated path components in an array (or perhaps an associative array) which you could then use in some looping scheme to create the dir structure when you have the needed data. Honestly, that doesn't sound like a lot of benefit, but it may tidy things up depending on your final loop logic (or make it worse...) Good luck.

Comment: Close you can get is `mkdir -p $(pwd)/OUTPUT/TOP1/MID1_{1,2,3} $(pwd)/OUTPUT/TOP2 $(pwd)/OUTPUT/TOP3/MID1_{1,2}`

Comment: Ah that is clever/handy @7171u ! Can you make it a solution. It gets me close enough to where I can work out the rest... would like to give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Parameter Expansion that lists all names of vars that have some prefix:

```
${!prefix@}
```

If we change the names of the variables used to some uniform format, and sort them in the order they need to be created, this will solve your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
outDir=$( pwd )
outDir01=${outDir}/OUTPUT
outDir02=${outDir01}/TOP1
outDir03=${outDir02}/MID1_1
outDir04=${outDir02}/MID1_2
outDir05=${outDir02}/MID1_3
outDir06=${outDir05}/BOT_1
outDir07=${outDir01}/TOP2
outDir08=${outDir01}/TOP3
outDir09=${outDir02}/MID3_1
outDir10=${outDir02}/MID3_2

for d in "${!outDir@}"; do
    [[ $d == outDir ]] && continue
    if  [[ -e "${!d}" ]]; then
        [[ -f "${!d}" ]] && echo "A file named ${!d} exist"
        [[ -d "${!d}" ]] && echo "A directory named ${!d} already exist"
        exit 2
    else
        echo \
        mkdir "${!d}"
        if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
            echo "mkdir was unable to create ${!d}"
            exit 3
        fi
    fi
done
```

The script has an `echo \` for you to see what it will do. If you agree with the listed actions, comment out that line (add a `#`: `# echo \`).

However, the simplest way to do all of this is (but quite more difficult to maintain):

```
$ mkdir -p ./OUTPUT/TOP{1/MID{1_{1,2,3/BOT_1},3_{1,2}},2,3}
$ tree OUTPUT/
OUTPUT/
├── TOP1
│   ├── MID1_1
│   ├── MID1_2
│   ├── MID1_3
│   │   └── BOT_1
│   ├── MID3_1
│   └── MID3_2
├── TOP2
└── TOP3
```